# How to pass output as command line argument in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have this two step bash command:

```
L=`wc -l testfile | cut -d' ' -f1`
myprogram testfile $L testfile.out
```

Long story short, `myprogram` needs the line count as an input.

**I want to combine this into one line.**

This does **not** work because using redirect `|` to `-` passes stdout stream as a file, not a string.

```
wc -l testfile | cut -d' ' -f1 | myprogram testfile - testfile.out
```

Is there a way to combine this into one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
myprogram testfile $(wc -l < testfile) testfile.out
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way, `wc -l < testfile` is evaluated together with the call of the program and you have both commands combined.

Note `wc -l < file` returns you just the number, so you don't have to do `cut` or any other thing to clean the output.

Comment: Or myprogram testfile """ wc -l < testfile """  testfile.out with oblic qote instead of """""

Comment: @CosminMihai yep! Only that in general `$()` is preferred --> [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: @CosminMihai in many cases they are the same, it just hurts if you want to nest them. If you are doing ` it is not possible! (And also, see how complicated it is to write them in comments :D)